# Issue with XIP on NXP MIMXRT1015

Tags: microcontroller, flash, nxp

I am working on the board bring up for a board using the NXP MIMXRT1015 crossover MCU. The design is pretty much a copy of the respective EVK including the same QSPI flash chip.

**Software Observations:**

I can't seem to successfully run code from flash. I can program the flash successfully using a JLINK, but using the the MCU-LINK pro and CMSIS-DAP configuration the programming fails. Whenever it is programmed with the JLink I can read the flash memory back and it matches the hex file that it was programmed with.

Whenever I go to debug, it never seems to reach the reset vector. If I pause the execution the program, the counter is in the 0x20000 range which I presume is the bootloader section.

The disassembly has no debug information in that region so I can't really tell. The code execution does move forward and I can read the status registers, but it never reaches the 0x6000000 address the flash is mapped to.

I can, however, execute the code from RAM and it works fine, so the hardware does work to some extent.

**Hardware Observations:**

Upon boot the MCU does in fact execute some QSPI commands. I can see the clock and it is running at the correct frequency I used for the XIP config. After maybe half a second or so the QSPI communication stops and the board does nothing. My initial guess is that the processor is just moving the code to RAM, but I am not sure.

Upon boot an LED I have attached to GPIO 2 pin 5 flashes. I am not sure if this is just the outputs being set up by the processor or some boot information.

I have boot configurations using DIP switches on the board. The flashing is responsive to the correct configuration of the switches.

Does anyone have experience with the processors or maybe some ideas? I am running out of them.

Comment: "My initial guess is that the processor is just moving the code to RAM" - why would it be doing that? Afaik, XIP typically means that the code is being eXecuted In Place directly out of the external QuadSPI flash. In a different NXP MCU I worked with in the past I had to jump through some extra hoops to make it copy the code from QuadSPI flash into RAM before it would execute it there. So which do you actually want here - XIP directly from the QSPI flash, or copy the code to RAM and execute it from there?

Comment: @brhans, I think the OP's question says that it shouldn't be copying the program to RAM but the QSPI behaviour makes it look as though it is. Maybe the MCU configuration is wrong and what should be XIP is in fact 'boot from FEPROM into RAM'.